# Can a cubit inside feature "A" pull from a repository inside feature "B"? Is this bad design?

Tags: flutter, design-patterns, architecture, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm using a Cubit-repository-datasource design separated by feature.

Title mostly says it all, but to extrapolate: I have an authentication Cubit. It is under the `/authentication` feature. I have another feature, `/posts` , that needs an access token from the `/authentication` feature to send an API request. This token is provided to it from the widget tree (authentication cubit is provided from the top of the widget tree). When a method from `/posts`'s cubit is called: `getPosts(int numOfPosts, String accessToken)`, it takes an access token from the provided widget tree's authentication cubit and passes it to the posts cubit. From here, it sends the request down to the repository layer, then to the data layer.

HOWEVER, what happens if the token is invalid? What happens if it has been tampered with? What happens if it's null? Then, I'd like the token to first be refreshed, and then to repeat the same call for posts using the refreshed access token. However, that "refresh the access token" method is inside the authentication cubit, not the posts cubit. How then should I call it? Can I call the `refreshAccessToken()` method (inside the `/authentication` feature's repository or data layer) from inside the repository or data layer of the /posts feature?

Is this sort of "crossing-feature" bad?

Thanks!

Comment: IMO tokens shouldn't be shared through blocs/cubits nor navigation, you should have a rest API service built apart and call this service from your bloc/cubit. Also, you could save your token once obtained with something like [flutter secure storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) and retrieve it from there when you need it. How you handle your tokens after invalidation or outdated is up to you.

Comment: @FabriBertani My refresh token is stored using flutter_secure_storage, but my access token is stored in memory as it is used with nearly every single request. The access token is inside the `User.accessToken` state of the `AuthenticationCubit`'s `AuthenticationState`. Wouldn't this be a more efficient solution? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second the comment made by @FabriBertani. The bloc/cubit shouldn't know anything about *how* to get the posts. It should just do `getPosts(int numberOfPosts)`.

That method should e.g. come from an interface (abstract class in Dart) which in turn is implemented in a different layer (e.g. data/repository/service layer).

That implementation can then in turn handle what is needed to fetch the data from your API. It could e.g. have an authentication service injected to it from where it gets the token.

Comment: Great answer! Makes sense. I have a follow up about how I managed the situation: I’ve went and injected an `ApiHandler` class through dependency injection that includes an http (Dio) client for managing tokens. It resides in the `data` layer, and now no other layer has to ever think about tokens - it’s all automatic.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.